# How to model a one-port (reflection) measurement in SPICE?

Tags: ltspice, spice, s-parameters

I have the equivalent circuit for an antenna and I would like to use SPICE to simulate the \$S_{11}\$ (reflection coefficient) response.

I know how to simulate two-port measurements (like shown [here](http://wireless-square.com/2016/11/01/s-parameters-with-ltspice/)), but how would I simulate a one-port measurement?

Comment: You are basically trying to convert S11 into an impedance?

Comment: I am not entirely sure I get your question (probably because I am terribly undereducated in all of this). I am trying to use SPICE to determine S11 of a one-port network (I think this is equivalent to determining its input impedance), however I am unsure of the circuit and the variation of presumably the .net command to use to do this.
Disclaimer: this might be a very dumb question, I am quite inexperienced in circuits and their simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use an AC simulation to find the input impedance of your 1-port, then calculate the reflection coefficient (\$\Gamma\$ aka \$S_{11}\$) from the input impedance

$$\Gamma = \frac{Z_L-Z_0}{Z_L+Z_0}.$$

To find the input impedance, just excite your 1-port with a 1-A ideal source. Then the voltage you read across the terminals is numerically equal to the input impedance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The \$S_{11}\$ parameter can be readily obtained with the following simulation model without resorting to extra calculations.

[image: Ac simulation for S11]

In this model the capacitor is the DUT and the ac voltage source has no parasitic series resistance.

The net description of the circuit is

```
V1 N001 0 AC 1
C1 0 N001 1n Rser=0.26 Lser=2.24n
.ac dec 3000 1Meg 500Meg
.net V1 V1 rin=50 rout=50
.backanno
.end
```